# Unable to inject parameters properly?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, bind

```js
const curryByBind = (fn) => fn.length === 0 ? fn() : (arg) => fn.bind(null, arg);
const sum = (x,y) => x+y;
const sumMany = curryByBind(sum);

console.log(sumMany(1)(2)())
```

I'm trying to learn `curry` and attempting to inject arguments into function via `bind`, I was thinking `sumMany(1)` should return a function that can take `(2)` which eventually at last execute `fn()`, but I cant figure out which part gone wrong, it's saying `sumMany(...)(...) is not a function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curryByBind` is working fine: the only problem is that you ran out of arguments.

`sum(x, y)` takes two arguments. After calling `sumMany` with one argument (`sum`'s `x`), it returns a function expecting a single argument (`sum`'s `y`).

After you call *that* function with one argument, you have supplied values for all of `sum`'s arguments, so it returns 3. (Which is not a function, hence the error when you try calling it.)

`console.log(sumMany(1)(2))` logs 3, as expected.

Comment: hmm...then it's not really my intention..`sumMany` should be able to take in any random number of args and at last when no args, executes it, wondering if you have any idea about that?

Comment: The [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) has each call taking one argument: there's no need for an extra zero-argument call at the end. However, if you want to defer execution at the end with a final zero-argument call, you can add another layer with something like:
`const deferredCurry = (fn) => fn.length === 0 ? fn() : (arg) => ((...more) => () => fn(arg, ...more))`
Then, with `const sumMany = deferredCurry((x, y) => x + y)`, `sumMany(1)(2)()` will work as you intended.

Comment: One other point about `curryByBind`: it only curries the first argument. If you want a version that works for any number of arguments (so that a four-argument version of `sum` could work like `sumMany(1)(2)(3)(4)`), you'll need something that curries _recursively_. There's a good example of how to do this [here](https://javascript.info/currying-partials#advanced-curry-implementation), but you may want to try it yourself first.